# HTML/JQ - play music to the end

Tags: html

I have this html in **index.php**:

```
<a href="other.php">other</a>

<audio id="music" controls>
    <source src="music/music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

And I need that audio was playing even if I click **other.php**. But when I click, so I want to play music where it was stopped on **index.php**.
Some ideas?

Comment: For this to work you will need to have a backend database like mysql to store the session information like the mp3 the user was playing and if the mp3 plays for 5 minutes,how many minutes the user had played before going to the other page.

Comment: @Gandalf: or cookies/local storage.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Yes,that would work too.

Comment: Any attempts to read the current play time and start playing from there again on the next page will result in audible gaps in playback – I would not recommend that at all. // In the “olden days”, continuous playback would have been achieved using frames, with a separate frame for the audio player that simply does not change source; nowadays this would be handled by not actually going to another page, but only switching out page content via JS/AJAX, so that the audio playing element stays “intact” as well.

Comment: There is the `timeupdate` which tells of the current playback position change event that occurs every 250ms.You can see list of events here http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/embedded-content.html#mediaevents

Comment: @CBroe You could always resume the playback a few seconds before the actual point you started playing to mitigate any gaps in playback.

Comment: @Gandalf: Changing to another page will take some time, and “deconstructing” the current document and building the new one might as well – I strongly doubt that you will be able to achieve truly gapless playback with such an approach cross-browser. Remember even simpler stuff such as showing an “activity indicator” GIF animation when submitting a form is already problematic in some browsers, and will just have the animation stop as soon as the request is send. And while seeing an animation stop doesn’t actually “hurt” much, our audible sense is much more sensitive to that kind of interruption.

Comment: @CBroe I totally agree.Cross browser gapless transition is a tall order.To truly have gapless playback,you would at least need access to the mp3 raw data in form byte array.

Answer (score 0):

The [`window.onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload) property allows you to register an function that runs when the user leaves the page.

The `<audio>` element has a [`currentTime` property](http://html5doctor.com/html5-audio-the-state-of-play/#properties) that tells you how much of the audio file has been played so far. If you set it to a new time, the audio element will skip to that point in the media file (although I think you’ll have to wait until the file has loaded).

You can save data from JavaScript to the user’s browser using [cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) and, where supported, [HTML5 Local Storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).

So — you could set a `window.onbeforeunload` handler function on index.php to save the `currentTime` of your audio element to a cookie or local storage, then set a `window.onload` handler function on other.php to read the saved `currentTime` and write it to the audio element there.

There Will Be Bugs. But it should be possible to make it work, give or take.